# How to find the distance between two sets of given latitude and longitude in Km or Mile?

Tags: geometry, spheres, geodesy

I was trying to find the solution in (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) format. The theory goes like this:
Assume I have these data:
lat1=56.986969769 , long1=-97.98689698
lat2=54.98789789, long2=-96.987890878

distance = SQRT((lat1-lat2)^2+(long1-long2)^2)

But this is not the distance that I want . Which theory should I apply to get the result in meter or miles?

Comment: If the surface of the planet can be approximated as a sphere, and the radius is known, check the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) and the [law of haversines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Law).

Comment: @peterwhy would you please take a look at my question again. Sorry I have to add some more data.

Comment: I think those links are still the relevant theories.

Comment: Do you want the distance that a plane would travel around the Earth’s surface? The path taken is called the “great circle” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle. You can calculate the arc of the circle between these two points.

Comment: Also see [Distance between points on Earth](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2465153/139123) or [How to calculate distance on a sphere with an earth-like coordination system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/369587/139123)